# having trouble with saving join model attributes in a has_many :through association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I'm having a really hard time with something that I think should be fairly straight forward. Hopefully someone out there can shed some light for me.

I have the following models with a has_many :through relationship.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :school_mascots, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_mascots

  has_many :mascots, :through => :school_mascots
end

class Mascot < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :school_mascots, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :schools, :through => :school_mascots
end

class SchoolMascot < ActiveRecord::Base
  # yes, it has a primary key (:id)

  attr_accessible :school_id
  belongs_to :school

  attr_accessible :mascot_id
  belongs_to :mascot
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mascot

  attr_accessible :nickname # this is an additional attribute on the join model
end
```

I'm trying to create a school record with the proper mascot associations. My schools controller looks like...

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @schools = School.all
  end

  def show
    @school = School.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @school = School.new(params[:school].except("mascots"))

    # add the mascot(s) to the new school; theoretically there could be more than one
    params[:school][:mascots].each do |mascot|
      # :id will be present if the mascot exists and can be reused
      # :nickname will be present if there is a nickname for the mascot
      # if :id is present, don't overwrite the mascot's data; although the nickname can be new since the join record is unique

      mascot_to_associate = {:mascot => Mascot.find_or_initialize_by_id(mascot[:id], mascot.except("nickname"))}

      if mascot[:nickname]
        mascot_to_associate.merge!(:nickname => mascot[:nickname])
      end

      @school.school_mascots.build_mascot(mascot_to_associate)
    end

    @school.save

    respond_with @school
  end
end
```

My request is structured like the following json (this example contains all possible inputs)...

```
{"school":{"name":"Univerisity of Virginia","mascots":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2","nickname":"Old Dominion"},{"name":"Hoos"},{"name":"Wah-hoo-wah","nickame":"Hoos"}]}}
```

So, the mascot could be one that is reused (1=Wahoos) without a nickname, one that is reused (2=Cavaliers) and also has a nickname, or one that is brand new and either has a nickname or not -- four possibilities.

I have been able to associate the schools and mascots, but once I introduce the nickname column on the join table it all goes downhill. I've tried all sorts of combinations for saving the associations, but I just can't seem to get it to work. The above was my latest attempt. But you name it and I've tried it. I just need some help. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!